# How to convert a String into a BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I'm trying to crawl a news website and I need to change one parameter. I changed it with replace with the next code:

```
while i < len(links):
    conn = urllib.urlopen(links[i])
    html = conn.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    t = html.replace('class="row bigbox container mi-df-local locked-single"', 'class="row bigbox container mi-df-local single-local"')
    n = str(t.find("div", attrs={'class':'entry cuerpo-noticias'}))
    print(p)
```

The problem is that "t" type is string and find with attributes is only applicable to types `<class 'BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup'>`. Do you know how can I convert "t" to that type?

Answer (score 18):

Just do the replacement *before parsing*:

```
html = html.replace('class="row bigbox container mi-df-local locked-single"', 'class="row bigbox container mi-df-local single-local"')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

---

Note that it would also be possible (I would even say **preferred**) to parse the HTML, locate the element(s) and *modify the attributes* of a `Tag` instance, e.g.:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for elm in soup.select(".row.bigbox.container.mi-df-local.locked-single"):
    elm["class"] = ["row", "bigbox", "container", "mi-df-local", "single-local"]
```

Note that `class` is a special [multi-valued attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) - that's why we are setting the value to a list of individual classes.

Demo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="row bigbox container mi-df-local locked-single">test</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for elm in soup.select(".row.bigbox.container.mi-df-local.locked-single"):
    elm["class"] = ["row", "bigbox", "container", "mi-df-local", "single-local"]

print(soup.prettify())
```

Now see how the `div` element classes were updated:

```
<div class="row bigbox container mi-df-local single-local">
 test
</div>
```

Comment: You must have been waiting for this one ;)

Comment: What is html, the library you are using?